# Drupal core patches with Commerce Kickstart 2.0

Tags: commerce

In the installation instructions for Commerce Kickstart 2.0, it alludes to the fact that Kickstart has two patches to the core.  See instructions at https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install.

Did these patches make it into Drupal 7.34? I am asking because I don't want an install of Drupal core with Commerce Kickstart; I just want the Commerce Kickstart code without the core. I don't want to use the installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on the content of the [drupal-org-core.make](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_kickstart/tree/drupal-org-core.make) file that comes with the distribution, I can say the patches are not part of Drupal 7.34. In fact the make files requires Drupal 7.34, and then lists the patches to apply.

```
projects[drupal][version] = 7.34

; Patches for Core
projects[drupal][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/issues/install-redirect-on-empty-database-728702-36.patch"
projects[drupal][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/drupal-1470656-14.patch"
projects[drupal][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/drupal-865536-204.patch"
projects[drupal][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/issues/drupal-7.x-allow_profile_change_sys_req-1772316-28.patch"
projects[drupal][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/1275902-15-entity_uri_callback-D7.patch"
```

You could apply those patch manually, but you would still be missing all the patches the distribution is applying to third-party modules. See all the lines containing `[patch][]` in the [drupal-org.make](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_kickstart/tree/drupal-org.make) file. The following lines are the ones for the Features module, but you can find more lines for other modules.

```
projects[features][version] = 1.0
projects[features][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/1572578-part-one.patch"
projects[features][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/1597186-1-features-do-not-cache-includes.patch"
projects[features][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/927566-multiple-link_path.patch"
projects[features][patch][] = "http://drupal.org/files/1669720-fix-features-flush-cache.patch"
```

Comment: Thank you for such a great response.   I have decided to just use the installer.  I would like to vote this answer up, but I don't have enough reputation yet.  I am a newbie.